# 'map-advanced-marker' component not found after upgrading @angular/google-maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, node-modules, google-maps-markers, angular-components

I'm using the google-maps Angular component here: https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/google-maps

and I'm getting a deprecation message when running the <map-marker> component in my Angular app that show the message use advanced marker (bottom).

So I tried updating with > npm add @angular/google-maps and I'm now using version 15.2.9, but I can't see or access any <map-advanced-marker>
component.

**Question** - Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

**Message**

> As of February 21st, 2024, google.maps.Marker is deprecated. Please use google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement instead. At this time, google.maps.Marker is not scheduled to be discontinued, but google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement is recommended over google.maps.Marker. While google.maps.Marker will continue to receive bug fixes for any major regressions, existing bugs in google.maps.Marker will not be addressed. At least 12 months notice will be given before support is discontinued. Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/deprecations for additional details and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/migration for the migration guide.